# How to connecting a 3-tier application in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, 3-tier

I want to make a 3-tier application.

I'm using MS SQL for a Database, connected to the "BL" with Repositories and Unit of work (using Entity). And I want to connect the Web API to the BL. I have used SOAP to connect the Web API and the BL in the past, but how can i connect them without it, and without using direct references (so they can be separated).

If there is no need for a separation can you elaborate why?

Comment: Why soap for a Web API, it should take Http Calls, as it defines Http end point. Soap is for a Web service communication

Comment: It's hard to say way you wouldn't need the separation without knowing why you think you do need separation.  What is wrong with the WebAPI directly referencing the BL?

Comment: I always prefer to keep things as separate as possible. As for the SOAP, it was another legacy project.

Comment: ok then: separation for the sake of separation is no reason for separation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you are using a REST API (Web API) on top of a SOAP API. This is counter-productive. These two components should both be entry points to your BL and should exist parallel to each other (no on top of each other), with no dependencies between them.

As to your main question, adding another layer of abstraction between the BL and an API will bring a lot of overhead with little advantage. The BL can probably exists as a separate project library that you can reference in both the SOAP and the REST API.

Comment: The SOAP thing was because of legacy reasons, not on my current project.Now I'm using strictly WEB API

Comment: Yah, that seems to be the trend. Reference the BL directly in the Web API is expected, though. The REST API itself will be the "separate", platform-independent component that you can consume from different apps implementations.